# Django form choicefield doesn't rendering empty field

Tags: python, django

I have a form that has a choicefield,

```
choice as follow - TYPE = (('','Select type'), ('college', 'College'), ('university', 'University'))

class Form(ModelForm):
      type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE)
```

As the document says

````
Unless blank=False is set on the field along with a default then a label containing "---------" will be rendered with the select box. To override this behavior, add a tuple to choices containing None; e.g. (None, 'Your String For Display'). Alternatively, you can use an empty string instead of None where this makes sense - such as on a CharField.```

I tried usign '' & None, both doesnt work ! 

It just shows the 'Select type' and immediately disappears ! Please help
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing this part :
"Unless blank=False is set on the field along with a default "

I don't see any default and blank flag on your snippet.

```
TYPE = [(None,'Select type'), ('college', 'College'), ('university', 'University')]

class Form(ModelForm):
      type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE, default=None, blank=False)
```

Does this work for you ?